# Layout controller in mvc, uncertain about implemination

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

Hey guys I've got this function:

```
if (Cookies.CheckIfCookiesExists())
{
    int.TryParse(Cookies.getWorkerCookieId("u-Site_Admin"), out uid);
    var worker = unitOfWork.Workers.Get(uid);
    ViewBag.isSuperAdmin = worker.IsSuperAdmin;
}
```

I want to pass the `isSuperAdmin` property down to the layout, and I need a controller to do this check every time the user switches between tabs.

My home controller returns this view:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "";
    ViewBag.isSuperAdmin = ViewBag.isSuperAdmin;
}
```

Inside the layout what I care about is the Aside page:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/partials/_aside.cshtml"); }
```

How would I go about achieving this? Basically the problem is the ViewBag value is lost like I've stated.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the controller, set the ViewBag property.
2. Render the partial view within the view. Note that I'm using `Html.Partial()` instead of `Html.RenderPartial`.
3. The ViewBag property will be passed to the partial view.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        ViewBag.isSuperAdmin = true;
        return View();
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/partials/_aside.cshtml")
```

Partial View:

```
<h3>ViewBag.isSuperAdmin = @ViewBag.isSuperAdmin</h3>
```

Result:

[image]